# Why when Earphone is plugged in the headphone front panel, its shows a converse status?

Tags: audio, motherboard, speakers, headphones, realtek-hd-audio

#### Problem

- When AUDIO port is not connected to Motherboard (not using headphone front panel)

  - When I plug in the Earphone at the rear  panel -> rear panel has sound (everything is fine)
- When AUDIO port is connected to Motherboard (try to use headphone front panel)

  4 cases::

  - When I plug in the Earphone at the rear  panel -> no sound; Realtek shows rear & front panel is plugged in

    [image]
  - When I plug in the Earphone at the front panel -> no sound; Realtek shows nothing is plugged in

    [image]
  - When I plug in nothing -> no sound; Realtek shows front panel is plugged in

    (so, it shows the converse status:

    **if I plugin the front panel -> shows front panel is not plugged in**;

    **if I dont plugin the front panel -> shows front panel is plugged in**)

    [image]
  - When I plug in the Earphone at the rear & front panel -> rear panel has sound; Realtek shows rear panel is plugged in

    [image]

##### Question

Why such Converse status (behavior)?

How can I use the Headphone on the headphone front panel properly?

(Is this an hardware problem? (ie: it just my headphone front panel is broken?))

##### Using:

- Realtek HD Audio
- Win10

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Disable front panel jack detection - in Realtek HD Audio

[image: Disable front panel jack detection]

- (now the headphone front panel should always be on (doesnt change when you plug in Earphone or not))
- (no idea why)